# How to create a nested menu using TailwindCss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I tried the code this way but I do not know how I can display the menus using the Hover class.

[image]

```html
<ul>
    <li class="relative">
        <a href="#">Lang</a>
        <ul class="absolute p- ">
            <li class=" w-36 ">
                <a href="#">JAVA</a>
                <ul class="absolute p-3">
                    <li class="w-36">Java 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```